# Microsoft AppCenter - Network error backing off and retrying

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I previously integrated Microsoft AppCenter 3.4.3 in my Xamarin iOS and Android app, for crash, analytics and push.

Today I upgraded AppCenter to version 4.1.0.  I did this intentionally because of Microsoft.AppCenter.Push is no longer supported.  4.1.0 to strips out all push references and dependencies.

I noticed in the debug console that after a crash and restart of the app App Center logged that it couldn't connect to the server and started backing-off to retry later.  Fair enough, except I do have internet access and the error implied it was permanent (host not found - or to that effect).

I usually copy the logs but on this occasion, I didn't ‍♂️ I'll update this bug when I next see it.

I believe since upgrading to 4.1.0 the backing-off started - I don't recall it happening with 3.4.3.

Looking at the AppCenter migration page [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/migration/apple-sdk-update) it would seem I should have changed the way `AppCenter.Start` is initialised, however, the method signatures offered by the Xamarin AppCenter NuGet have remained the same as 3.4.3 (yes I have double-checked the shared project and Android project NuGet versions and the package manager didn't downgrade them).

For example, I was previously and continue to use `AppCenter.start`, yet according to the docs it used to be `MSAppCenter.start` (note the MS prefix).  If this was true then I should have needed to tweak them and I haven't changed a single line of code, everything compiles and runs okay.

Q1 - Is Microsoft.AppCenter, Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes 4.1.0 okay to use in a Xamarin Forms project?

Q2 - Should I consider reverting to 3.4.3?

Q3 - How come the Xamarin for Nuget 4.1.0 doesn't reflect the naming changes?

Q4 - Is 4.1.0 Android-X friendly?

Note I'm using the Xamarin Forms, 4.8.0.1821

Comment: I believe the docs you are linking to are for native iOS, not Xamarin

Comment: Hi, whether you have use the latest version of Xamarin Forms to check this?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT we aren't using the 5.x branch of XF but 4.8.0.1821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 - Yes, App Center .NET SDK is compatible with `Xamarin.Forms`

Q2 - Please share the verbose logs in [your GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/issues/1495) so we can help you to determine the cause and fix this.

Q3 - Naming changes affect only iOS native code, .NET SDK deals with it internally. No changes on the application side required.

Q4 - There are no related changes between 3.4.3 and 4.1.0. If you have any problems please let us know (create an issue on GitHub).

Comment: Thank you @Ivan - I was previously experiencing a 'HTTP 502 - Bad Gateway' error and now I suspect that it was a temporary issue at AppCenter. The app has recently crashed and the details were captured in the App Center web portal, under the crashes page.  This was tested using a 'release' configuration, so I'm pretty confident it's okay.